# Can we do ethereum transaction for free on private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

I am very new to ethereum Blockchain. Please give some suggestion regarding one query regarding gas fee.

Can we do ethereum transaction and smart contract deployment for free on private blockchain using POA consensus  or still I have to pay ether(dummy ether)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You control the miners in the private network, so you just need to customize them to accept transactions with gasPrice = 0.

From the Parity documentation:

```
--gasprice WEI                   Minimum amount of Wei per GAS to be paid for a
                                 transaction to be accepted for mining. Overrides
                                 --basic-tx-usd.
```

Note that this doesn't change how gas itself works in the network. You still have gas limits and can generate out of gas errors. The only difference is that the client is saying it will pay 0 for gas on a transaction and the miner is staying it is willing to accept transactions at 0 price.

**Or if using GETH**

```
$ geth --networkid 29462 --datadir "./data" --gasprice 0 --nodiscover --port 31313
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318479/how-to-make-sure-transactions-take-0-fee-in-a-private-ethereum-blockchain)

Comment: Thanks @Hamza, however I want to apply this gas price 0 using POA consensus. would be it possible?

Comment: try this, https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

Answer (score -1):

You will still have to pay "ETH" in order to pay for the cost of the opcodes, but these "ETH" that you are transaction do not have any value.

Since this is a different network, the "ETH" is *not* the same as it is on the main network, therefore there is no value to it (unless you do  something to give it a value). This is the same reason that Rinkeby ETH and Ropsten ETH have no value