# What settings should a private PoA blockchain have to be free to use? ( No ether in use )

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, gas-price, poa, opcode

I am a total noob in creating blockchains, and I am trying to make one using geth with PoA.

I want to make a PoA private blockchain where transactions and smart contracts ( usage and deployments ) are totally free ( i am not planning on using ether at all, and there will be just interaction with and between smart contracts in the blockchain ) .

Will setting `--gasFee 0` on every node do the trick as seen in this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68447/can-we-do-ethereum-transaction-for-free-on-private-blockchain), since OPCODES transactions fee work with gas as well?

I've also seen this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92454/remove-ether-from-poa-private-network) with a suggested solution but there's no feedback.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions on how to properly achieve, please explain as much as possible since I've said before, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very important to get familiar with geth Ethereum client first.
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network#initializing-geth-database

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/87643)